# Comparison (operator's overloading) of large and sophisticated structures in c++

Tags: c++, scripting, automation, comparison-operators

We must face serious issue while prepraing my project and working on code in c++.
My code is build on multiple structures/classes where one is included in another.
Finaly i will have to compare all these structures between themselves. 
In this case it is impossible (or requres terrible effort) to overload comparison operators for everything. Do you perhaps have any idea how to approach this issue? I considered writing a script which would go through all classes and subclasses and add required operators to avoid writing them. 
Have you ever encountered this and found solution? 
I am thankful for all advices in advance.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Have you considered templating the operator overloading? Just befriend what operators you can.

Comment: Seriously, I would just bite the bullet and implement all the needed compare operators.  Are you talking about more than 100 classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can implement a common interface in each of the classes that provides the tools necessary to compare the various different classes. In this way you can write just one single `operator==` which operates on the interfaces without needing to know about the low level details.